# Start a new Android projekt with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

i start a new Android projekt with Android Studio and become this error:

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.pom'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your build.gradle Module:app

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
        }}
```

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Let me know if this method is working. Because if not, there are few more methods.